# Difference between below flume sink configuration

Tags: flume-ng

I have very confused about below three sink configuration in flume . please clarify me

**CONF1**

```
a1.sinks.k1.type = hdfs
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.path = /flume/events/
```

**CONF2**

```
a1.sinks.k1.type = hdfs
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.path = hdfs://localhost:9000/flume/events/
```

**CONF3**

```
a1.sinks.k1.type = file_roll
a1.sinks.k1.sink.directory = /var/log/flume
```

what are specific use case for each of this sink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Conf1** and **Conf2** are basically the same. Both of them have hdfs sink and the data is being written to HDFS. The only difference is that in one case you are giving absolute path.

**Conf3** is a local file roll sink where data is being store into local disk and compared to HDFS.